# I want to count the answers of a multiple choice questions, but it's only counting the single entries

Tags: mysql, count

```
$sql = "select count(*) as total_count,
    
      COUNT(if(O13b= '1',1,null))  AS anganwadi,
      COUNT(if(O13b = '2',1,null)) AS manganwadi,
      COUNT(if(O13b = '3',1,null)) AS Noanganwadi,
      COUNT(if(O13b = '4',1,null)) AS Noangan,
      COUNT(if(O13b = '5',1,null)) AS Noan,
      COUNT(if(O13b = '6',1,null)) AS RKS ,
      COUNT(if(O13b = '7',1,null)) AS SDMC,
      COUNT(if(O13b = '8',1,null)) AS Mamta,
      COUNT(if(O13b = '9',1,null)) AS trainings,
      COUNT(if(O13b = '10',1,null)) AS Livelihood,
      COUNT(if(O13b = '11',1,null)) AS Oth 
      
    FROM identification";
```

The query only collects the entries of 1 on the column `O12b` but does not count where the values were 1,2 or 1,2,5 etc

How do I get these counts?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please go to dbfiddle.uk and choose your version of MySQL, create your tables, input some sample data and give us the desired result. Then put all of that back in the question (use the [Edit] link under the question).

Comment: Please give a [mcve] with sample data and expected output. Do you perhaps need `>= AND <` style conditions?

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNT(if(O13b = '5',1,null)) AS Noan,
```

Change to one of these, depending on the desired outcome:

```
SUM(O13b = '5') AS Noan,
COALESCE(SUM(O13b = '5'), 'none') AS Noan,
COALESCE(SUM(O13b = '5'), 0) AS Noan,
```

(The first one gives `NULL` when zero; this matches what you were trying.)